# Why do I get "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent" when I call Response.Redirect()?

Tags: asp.net, http-headers, response.redirect, httpexception

When I call `Response.Redirect(someUrl)` I get the following HttpException:

> Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.

Why do I get this? And how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

According to the MSDN documentation for `Response.Redirect(string url)`, it will throw an HttpException when "a redirection is attempted after the HTTP headers have been sent".  Since `Response.Redirect(string url)` uses the Http "Location" response header (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers#Responses), calling it will cause the headers to be sent to the client.  This means that if you call it a second time, or if you call it after you've caused the headers to be sent in some other way, you'll get the HttpException.

One way to guard against calling Response.Redirect() multiple times is to check the `Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected` property (bool) before calling it.

```
// Causes headers to be sent to the client (Http "Location" response header)
Response.Redirect("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
    // Will not be called
    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Yup exactly. This happens quite easily with ASP.NET MVC 4 and the Exception filters, etc. You also cannot change the HTTP Response Status Code once a redirect 301/302 has been issued.

Comment: I solved the issue by making all the properties on my page 'static'

Comment: making your properties static is a dangerous solution

Comment: How can the redirect be called a second time unless the ThreadAbortException (from the first time) is caught? :} "Calling Redirect is equivalent to calling Redirect with the second parameter (`endResponse`) set to true."

Comment: It's weird, but in a legacy webforms application `Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected` is false and I'm still getting this same exception (inside `Application_EndRequest` event method in Global.asax). I can't understand why.

Comment: Never use static properties in a web application or variable contents will leak between requests. @Sal

Answer (score 17):

Once you send any content at all to the client, the HTTP headers have already been sent.  A `Response.Redirect()` call works by sending special information in the headers that make the browser ask for a different URL.

Since the headers were already sent, asp.net can't do what you want (modify the headers)

You can get around this by a) either doing the Redirect before you do anything else, or b) try using `Response.Buffer = true` before you do anything else, to make sure that no output is sent to the client until the whole page is done executing.

Comment: For me  it doesn't work. I use .NET, MVC and I have a call inside controller's method. I still receive exception, although redirection happens.

Answer (score 8):

A Redirect can only happen if the first line in an HTTP message is "`HTTP/1.x 3xx Redirect Reason`".

If you already called `Response.Write()` or set some headers, it'll be too late for a redirect. You can try calling `Response.Headers.Clear()` before the Redirect to see if that helps.

Comment: I use `return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Authentication");` and I get that error

Comment: When I tried clearing the headers, I got System.PlatformNotSupportedException: This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.

Answer (score 3):

Just check if you have set the buffering option to false (by default its true). For response.redirect to work,

1. Buffering should be true,
2. you should not have sent more data using response.write which exceeds the default buffer size (in which case it will flush itself causing the headers to be sent) therefore disallowing you to redirect.

Comment: `Response.BufferOutput = true;` in the Action, in Controller ?

Answer (score 3):

Using 
`return RedirectPermanent(myUrl)` worked for me

Comment: I have Action and Controller

Answer (score 2):

You can also use below mentioned code

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>"); Response.Write("window.location = '" + redirect url + "'</script>");Response.Flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple answer for this:
You have been output something else, like text, or anything related to output from your page before you send your header. This affect why you get that error.

Just check your code for posible output or you can put the header on top of your method so it will be send first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to redirect after the headers have been sent (if, for instance, you are doing an error redirect from a partially-generated page), you can send some client Javascript (location.replace or location.href, etc.) to redirect to whatever URL you want.  Of course, that depends on what HTML has already been sent down.

Answer (score 1):

My Issue got resolved by adding the Exception Handler to handle
"Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent". this Error as shown below code

```
catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
        {
            // To Handle HTTP Exception "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent".
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {//Here you can put your context.response.redirect("page.aspx");}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using:
Response.RedirectToRoute("CultureEnabled", RouteData.Values);
instead of Response.Redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you don't use `Response`s' methods like `Response.Flush();` before your redirecting part.

Answer (score 1):

**Error**
Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.

**Suggestion**
If we use asp.net mvc and working on same controller and redirect to different Action then you do not need to write.. 
 **Response.Redirect("ActionName","ControllerName");**
 its better to use only 
 **return RedirectToAction("ActionName");**
 or 
 return View("ViewName");

Comment: I use ActionName from another ControllerName ?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect function probably works by using the 'refresh' http header (and maybe using a 30X code as well). Once the headers have been sent to the client, there is not way for the server to append that redirect command, its too late.

Answer (score 0):

If you get Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent then try this below code.

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.ClearError();
// Response.Headers.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Home/Login",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Home/Login",false);
```

The last parameter, if it is set to False, solves the issue but does not terminate the response for the current thread.

Answer (score -3):

There are 2 ways to fix this:

1. Just add a `return` statement after your `Response.Redirect(someUrl);`
   ( if the method signature is not "void", you will have to return that "type", of course )
   as so:

   Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

   return;

Note the return allows the server to perform the redirect...without it, the server wants to continue executing the rest of your code...

2. Make your `Response.Redirect(someUrl)` the LAST executed statement in the method that is throwing the exception. Replace your `Response.Redirect(someUrl)` with a string VARIABLE named "someUrl", and set it to the redirect location... as follows:

`//......some code`

```
string someUrl = String.Empty
```

.....some logic

```
if (x=y)
{
    // comment (original location of Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");)
    someUrl = "Login.aspx";
}
```

......more code

// MOVE your Response.Redirect to HERE (the end of the method):

```
Response.Redirect(someUrl);
return;
```

Comment: sorry but this makes not any sense to me. What should (in a void-returning method) that redundant `return` do? The `return` only defines that the method is completed. But when there's not any code left, the method is completed anyway. And storing an url in a variable doesn't change anything, I mean: why should it? The string is the same. The compiled thing doesn't make any difference between a string and a variable containing a string...: think about `x = 5`, so x is 5 but 5 is also 5.  even 10/2 would be 5... makes no difference neither