# ASP.NET Refresh the page after uploading image

Tags: asp.net, caching, uploading

I have an ASPX page where I am uploading an image to server for on a serverside button click event. In my page, it will show the available image if it exists.  When I upload an image, it will replace the old one with the new one. Now after uploading also the same image is getting displayed. How can tackle this? I used window.location.reload() javascript function to refresh, but then it is not working. It is posting the page again.

This is my code

```
    Do UploadImage(studentId,mode);  // Function to upload image
    StringBuilder sbc = new StringBuilder();

    sbc.Append("<script language='javascript'>");
    sbc.Append("alert('Upload process completed successfully!');");
    sbc.Append("window.location.reload()");
    sbc.Append("</script>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sbc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's being cached in the browser.  To overcome this - alter the url of the image.  This can be done by including a timestamp, version number, or guid in the image file name.

Answer (score 2):

Your browser is probably caching the image.  Either disable caching on the image or set up proper caching responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload from the server side

```
Response.Redirect(Request.URL)
```

Comment: I am getting Can not redirect after HTTP headers have been sent Message

Comment: You can refer to this thread - <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159523/why-do-i-get-cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-when-i-call-resp>

Answer (score 0):

A useful tool to debug this is [fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/). As others already suggested it's likely that the browser caches the old version of the image. If you are using IIS you can change the cache policy so that the browser always check for a newer version of the image.