# Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: c#, asp.net

When  I try to redirect to another page through `Response.Redirect(URL)` am getting the following error:- `System.Web.HttpException: Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.`

I wrote one `Response.Write("Sometext")`; and `Response.Flush()` before calling redirect Method.

In this case how do we use `Response.Redirect(URL)`?

I'm executing a Stored procedure through Asynch call. The SP will take almost 3 min to execute. By that time I'll get load balancer timeout error from Server because this application is running in Cloud computer. For avoiding load balancer timeout I'm writing some text to browser (`response.write()` and `Flush()` ) .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent" when I call Response.Redirect()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159523/why-do-i-get-cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-when-i-call-res)

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure that you do not write/flush *anything* before trying to send a HTTP header.
After sending headers there is ***no proper way*** to do a redirect as the only things you can do are outputting JavaScript to do the redirect (bad) or sending a 'meta refresh/location' tag which will most likely not be at the correct position (inside HEAD) and thus result in invalid html.

Comment: I'm executing a Stored procedure through Asynch call. The SP will take almost 3 min to execute. By that time I'll get load balancer timeout error from Server because this application is running in Cloud computer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and same approach. You might want to try using a javascript instead of directly calling Response.Redirect.

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
Response.Write("window.location = '" + url + "'</script>");
Response.Flush();
```

Worked fine with me however I still need to check it on different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
                    Response.Redirect("~/RMSPlusErrorPage.aspx?ErrorID=" + 100, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Response.Redirect as you've gone past headers and written out "Sometext". You have to check (redirect condition) before you start writing out data to the client or make a META redirect.

If you want one of those pages that shows text and redirects after 5s META is your option.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get this error, if you redirect before the rendering of your page begins (for example when you redirect from the `Load` or `PreRender` events of the page).

---

I see now in your comments, that you would like to redirect after a long-running stored procedure completes. You might have to use a different approach in this case.

You could put for example an AJAX `UpdatePanel` with a `Timer` on your page, and the Timer could check in every few seconds whether the stored procedure has completed, and then do the redirection.

This approach also has the advantage, that you can put some "in progress" message on the page, while the procedure is running, so your user would know, that things are still happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

```
   catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
        {
            // To Handle HTTP Exception "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent".
        }
   catch (Exception e)
        {//Here you can put your context.response.redirect("page.aspx");}
```

Comment: full sample about it ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, cause of the problem is that loading data in the scroll gridview is taking a long time. And before gridview data is not loaded completely, but I press the redirect button. I get this error.

You can lessen your data get

or

before loading completion prevent to press redirect button