# I am getting exception "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent" when redirecting to another page

Tags: asp.net

I am getting exception

```
"Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent."
```

when on doing `Response.Redirect("Home.aspx")`.

How can i solve this? 
I tried giving `Response.Flush()` before redirecting.

Comment: Duplicate to question and resolution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159523/why-do-i-get-cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-when-i-call-resp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent" when I call Response.Redirect(url)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159523/why-do-i-get-cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-when-i-call-resp)

Comment: i tried the solution from the above thread. I am not able to fix the issue... Title of my tread may be duplicate, but the issue causing might be some other....

Comment: I have a page which inherits from a base page where which checks whether the user has the permission to access the page. if the user has the permission then would be redirecting to the requested page, if not redirecting the user to access denied page. this check happens on the OnInt Method of the BasePage.

Comment: Just a thought, it could be to do with the hierarchy of calls - have you tried changing OnInit to OnLoad?

Comment: If the answers in the other question aren't helping you (e.g. the second highest voted one mentions making sure `Response.Buffer` is set true before anything else happens), then you're going to have to show us more of your code if you expect us to diagnose it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent" when I call Response.Redirect()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159523/why-do-i-get-cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-when-i-call-res)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is the `Response.Flush()` prior to redirecting.  With HTTP you get **one** response for **one** request.  Your browser requested the page only once, and I suspect you're trying to respond twice:

```
Response.Flush(); //First Response
Response.Redirect("Home.aspx"); //Second Response
```

Therefore taking this out the `Response.Flush()` will solve your problem.

Comment: because of this error i added Response.Flush(), even if i remove i am getting the same error.

Comment: Then you've likely got another response somewhere, do a find or post up some code

Answer (score 0):

In my case, cause of the problem is that loading data in the scroll gridview is taking a long time. And before gridview data is not loaded exactly, but I press the redirect button.

Trying solve problem may be:

+lessen your data get

or

+before loading completion prevent to press redirect button

Answer (score -3):

I just ran across this problem in a little different way. I had two Response.Redirect calls that were not wrapped in isolated branches of code. Worked fine in Chrome, but IE did not like it. It was an easy fix since I had two "if" statements. I just turned the second one into an "else if" like so...

```
if (QueryString("reset") == "1")
{
    // User is resetting password
    Response.Redirect("/Account/ResetPassword.aspx");
}
else if (DataUtils.IsInt(QueryString("id")))
{
    // User is authenticating...completing signup
    Response.Redirect("/Account/Activate.aspx");
}
```