# MVC Partial view Inside partial view with Timer

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have a partial view which is rendered like this in my main view by calling the function.

```
function LoadPartialView1(){  url = ROOT + "ControllerName/PartialView1_PV?Dashboard=" + Dashboard + "&department=" + department;
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#divPartial').html(data);
        });  }
```

In this partial view  let us imagine I am getting list of Employees in a particular department.
Against each employee I need to append the work details of today,So in this PartialView1_PV I am calling another partial view like this

```
 <div>
  @Html.Action("WorkDetails", "ControllerName", new { EmployeeId= item.EmployeeId})
  </div>
```

Here  I am able to get the details and display it ,but I have a timer running and it is calling the LoadPartialView1() function in each 10 seconds.In my localhost it is running fine and getting refreshed ,but when I published it in the server Iam getting error saying

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot redirect after HTTP
>   headers have been sent.

I have referred to other questions like [Stackoverflow qustion1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159523/why-do-i-get-cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-when-i-call-res),
[StackOverflow question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646762/i-am-getting-exception-cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-when) but still no go.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you doing any redirection from your code ?, Have you tried the same by commenting the second partial view calling ?

Comment: There is no redirection Iam doing.

Comment: I will try with commenting the second second portion.

Comment: ok please try and let us know the result

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Once the second partial view is commented ,the error is not coming.

Comment: Ok, So the issue is not related with calling partial view many times via Ajax, its related to the redirection. Can you please try to call the second partial view using @Html.RenderAction

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Can you please give the  format of calling RenderAction with parameter as I used for Action.

Comment: @Html.RenderAction("WorkDetails", "ControllerName", new { EmployeeId= item.EmployeeId})

Comment: Thanks for your comment,but RenderAction is not taking this way.It is showing error-"Cannot implicitly convert type void to object"

Comment: what are you getting from your controller ? what is the type of your controller action ?are you returning html content ??

Comment: look into your second partial view code / javascript and make sure no where in the partial view uses a page redirection.