# asp.net postback

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get “Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent” when I call Response.Redirect()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159523/why-do-i-get-cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-when-i-call-res)

Can I do something like this :

```
Response.Write(displaying some gif);

Response.Flush();

Thread.Sleep(6000);

Response.Write(@"<script>document.getElementById('loading').style.display='none';</script>");

Response.Buffer = true;

Response.Redirect("some URL")
```

Because I get this exception Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent if I try.Can anyone help me out how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cool kids might be using AJAX/JavaScript these days but if that's more advanced than you want to get into right now, here's an old-school way of doing something similar:

Create a "landing" page that shows the GIF and which also has in it's `<head>` tag, `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="6;url=http://yourURL/">` where 6 is the number of seconds to wait before redirecting to the "real" page in the `URL=` part.

Note that animated GIFs may stop animating between the time the Refresh kicks off and when your real page's content arrives.