# .NET MVC - What to return when the Response is set to redirect from an attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I have an attribute [RedirectSSL] that may or may not redirect a http-request to a corresponding https-request under some conditions:

```
[RedirectSSL]
public class ControllerA : Controller(){
    public ActionResult MethodA()
    {
        if (SomeExpression)
            return RedirectToAction("MethodB", "ControllerA");
        return RedirectToAction("MethodC", "ControllerA");
    }
    public ActionResult MethodB()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult MethodC()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that it throws a System.Web.HttpException whenever the RedirectSSL-attribute has called the Response's Redirect() method before the RedirectToAction() is returned. The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159523/why-do-i-get-cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-when-i-call-res) is to encapsulate the redirects within an

```
if(!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected){ ... }
```

But what should be returned if this evaluates to false? An EmptyResult() would do I guess, but I don't like the way the code looks as it isn't clear to me by looking at it that it will redirect the client. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of calling `Response.Redirect` in the `RedirectSSL`, assign a `RedirectResult` to the `filterContext.Result`. It will thus prevent the action from being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionFilter` helps you decide if an action can be executed or not. You can bypass the action altogether by providing an `ActionResult` from the filter. Something along the lines of

```
public class RedirectSSLAttribute:ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("your url");
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm and is a much better solution than I was hoping for. Thanks!