# Page not loading while redirecting from another page when using return RedirectToAction()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am facing a strange situation that when I am trying to redirect to one page from another page it is not loading. When I checked by adding a break point the pointer is going to the controller and also to the view but not loading. Can anyone explain the reason and possible solution.

After checking error log I got following details

```
2016-09-27 09:18:27,927 [7] ERROR PPMS.Web.Controllers.BaseController [(null)] - { Controller = TrackingDevice, Action = Add, Exception = System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
   at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.Redirect(String url)
   at PPMS.Web.CustomAttributes.SessionExpireAttribute.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) in d:\PPMS\PPMS.Web\CustomAttributes\SessionExpireAttribute.cs:line 20
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive(Int32 filterIndex)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive(Int32 filterIndex)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__31(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) }
```

Comment: "not loading" is a very broad statement. You need to provide more information. Take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you show your code, additionally add exception if any.

Comment: no exception is comming the problem is in my list page.At first list page will come but when i am trying to add new item, on submit it should redirect to the same list page at that time it is not comming

Comment: `Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent" when I call Response.Redirect()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159523/why-do-i-get-cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-when-i-call-res)

Comment: I found that my excecution is hitting the same controller twice but I am not able to find out why it is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that one of the Action Filters being used has created a response before the call to Redirect has been called. You can use

```
if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
// Will not be called
Response.Redirect(...);
```

to help here.
(see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159538/612512)).