# "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent" when doing RedirectToAction()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So my question is a little different than the others. For others, they were using the `Response.Redirect( url );` directly and so the fixes are just wrapping around it.

However, I have something like the following inside the same controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  // some other logic running inside this function...

  return RedirectToAction( "Result" );
}

public ActionResult Result()
{
   // Expecting calls being sent from Index

  return View ("done");
}
```

So I am not really calling Response.Redirect() directly, but RedirectToAction() probably calls Response.Redirect() eventually. In this case, what can I do?

These are the stack trace:

```
SYSTEM EXCEPTION:
- Message: Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.
- Source: System.Web

- Stack Trace:
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
   at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Comment: Seems pretty straight-forward to me. Somewhere before the redirect, you're modifying HTTP headers. However, given that you've redacted that code, who knows what's going on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent" when I call Response.Redirect()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159523/why-do-i-get-cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-when-i-call-res)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Response.Headers.Clear()` before `RedirectToAction`

Comment: Redirect to Action to another Controller: `RedirectToAction("Logout", "Authentication");`