# Resonse.Redirect(URL) is not working in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, global-asax

In my requirement i am returning custom error. in *global.asax* application error is not redirecting any other URL. `Response.Redirect(URL)`,`Server.Transfer(URL)` is not redirecting. it show *Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent*. i tried but not working. please try to help me.below is my code

```
try
        {
            Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
            ErrorLogger LogError = new ErrorLogger();

            // Handle HTTP errors
            if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
            {
                ex = (HttpException)Server.GetLastError();
                int httpCode = ex.GetHttpCode();

                // Filter for Error Codes and set text
                if (httpCode >= 400 && httpCode < 500)
                    ex = new HttpException
                          (httpCode, "Safe message for " + httpCode + " HTTP codes.", ex);
                else if (httpCode > 499)
                    ex = new HttpException
                         (ex.ErrorCode, "Safe message for " + httpCode + " HTTP codes.", ex);
                else
                    ex = new HttpException
                        (httpCode, "Safe message for unexpected HTTP codes.", ex);

                // Log the exception and notify system operators
                ErrorLogger.Error(ex);
                Server.ClearError();
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.Redirect("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
                if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
                    // Will not be called
                    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");

                //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('ErrorPage.aspx');", true);
                //Response.Write("<script> window.open('http://localhost:54749/ErrorPage.aspx','_blank'); </script>");
                //Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com", true);
                //Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorLogger.Error(exc);
                // LogError.NotifySystemOps(exc);
                // Clear the error from the server
                //Server.ClearError();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogger.Error(ex);
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent" when I call Response.Redirect()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159523/why-do-i-get-cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-when-i-call-res)

Comment: Is this MVC (as from your question tags)? If yes, try Context.Response.Redirect()

Comment: i already tried HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(URL). @Surjit SD

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN documentation for `Response.Redirect(string url)`, it will throw an HttpException when "a redirection is attempted after the HTTP headers have been sent". Since `Response.Redirect(string url)` uses the Http "Location" response header (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers#Responses), calling it will cause the headers to be sent to the client. This means that if you call it a second time, or if you call it after you've caused the headers to be sent in some other way, you'll get the HttpException.

One way to guard against calling `Response.Redirect()` multiple times is to check the `Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected property (bool)` before calling it.

// Causes headers to be sent to the client (`Http "Location" response header`)

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
    // Will not be called
    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

**Note*** *You cannot change the HTTP Response Status Code once a redirect 301/302 has been issued as well.*

Comment: i already tried. please see my code already implented on that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com", true);

can you tell us also which part of global.asax file you are using this code.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
}
```

or it is somewhere else

also try following code

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: i already tried your answers. and my code is in this method.            
 protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  }

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
this.Response.Redirect("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: same error ie: Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.

Comment: If you are using the ASP.NET MVC then for the error handling, use the filters (OnExecption) instead of global.asax

Comment: No.  i am using webapi

Comment: Form WebAPI also, you can manage the filters and send the Response with appropriate status code and message. At the web end where the API is called check the status code and redirect to error page

Comment: @chaitanay: What does `Response.Redirect` mean when this is a webapi project?