# Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent exception in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

In my asp.net application want to refresh the current page after user has download the excel file but every time the code throws an exception says:

> "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent".

I've already almost every solution on web but none of them worked for me. I've tried this approach 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159538/10056979) approach also but that also did work for me.

this is my code:

```
wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Docket_Cycle_Performance");
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = 
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
                   "attachment;filename=DocketCyclePerformance-" 
                     + System.DateTime.Now + ".xlsx");

using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
    MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
    Response.Flush();

    if (!Response.IsRequestBeingRedirected)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
    }
    Response.End();
}
```

Is there any solution of this problem..
Thanks!!

Comment: Why are you even redirecting them there? You send a file and then you want them to navigate away from it immediately? If you want them to just download it (instead of opening it in the browser) then the attachment; part of the disposition should be enough.

Comment: Hello, @Karl-JohanSjögren thankyou for your response, I just want to refresh the current page after user download the file.

Comment: That wont be possible from the server. Redirecting is done by setting the Location-header and headers needs to be at the start of the response. So even if you could set the header then your file would be ignored. I would suggest that you try fixing the refresh issue with javascript instead.

Comment: okie... I'll try thanks